# NavigationBar's titleView label missing after switching to Landscape in Master Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, master-detail, iphone-6-plus

In both portrait and landscape, when I push a UIViewController onto a navigationController stack, the titleView inside the detail VC's navigationBar looks fine.

Landscape:
[image: Landscape]
Portrait:

[image: Portrait]

BUT if I rotate the device from portrait to landscape, the titleView goes missing:

[image: Missing]

Has anyone encountered this weird bug before? I am not using any custom navigationItems and I'm not manually setting the titleView.

It seems that the titleView's origin is being set out of the bounds of the navigation item after looking at the view hierarchy:

[image: Views]

This is on an iPhone 6 Plus running iOS8.3

Comment: Facing this in 2020 on iOS14!

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the content of the navigation bar programatically in swift:

`viewController.title = "some title"`

When put into the view did load:
`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "some title"
}`

Try putting inside the viewDidLoad for landscape orientation only:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {             
   println("landscape")
self.title = "some title"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. I tried this but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: hmmm are you using auto layout? I find that often causes little bugs like this in Xcode 6

Comment: could you try running the above code in the viewDidLoad of the detail view? You might also want to try running that code for the landscape orientation only. I will amend my answer.